# Android device mirrored PC

Tags: android, android-studio, ddms

I would like to know if there is any possibility to mirror my android device in real time using android studio? Or anything else that may be used just with an usb or hdmi cable with no required registration?
I tried a couple of little software apps so far but there is a delay consinsting in more than 10 seconds until the action is mirrored on the pc.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can use a chromecast to mirror the display to your TV or anything that has HDMI input, so that should include most monitors

Answer (score 14):

I am using [Vysor](https://vysor.io/) which doesn't need registration, but free version limits the resolution, so it may not be optimal for certain purposes

Edit, I just discovered [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) which seems to work way better and even supports copy-pasting from PC to device

Comment: I agree with `scrcpy`. It is simple to use and easy to set up.

Comment: ++ for scrcpy. I'm gonna buy Vysor pro but scrcpy saved me 40$.

Comment: Wow, I wish software experiences were all like `scrcpy`. I'm on Windows, no installation, 30mb download, I literally opened the `.exe`, it assumed my Android was the one to show and it displayed it. No config, no selection, no adverts, just open and go. 10/10.

Answer (score 4):

Now you can do it with Android Studio https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#device-mirroring

Comment: Not working. :(

Comment: I assume you setup all the needed settings following the doc, so the issue might be related to your phone model. Which one are you using?

Comment: I tried different models but not working, Realme 6, Oppo A54, Samsung A31, Pixel 4, Pixel 6...that's why I'm wondering.

Comment: May I ask your Android Studio version?

Comment: Of course it's latest.

Comment: May I ask you which one?

Comment: Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 1

Comment: Could you just try the latest (as today) Beta version Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Beta 3?

Comment: Ok...let me give it a try

Comment: Hi. Don't know what was the problem but, it's working fine in the stable version, too.

Answer (score 3):

Now this feature is available in Android Studio Electric Eel Yay!

**Preference > Experimental > Device Mirroring**

Comment: Not working. :(

Answer (score -1):

You can try AllCast. http://www.omgchrome.com/cast-android-mirror-chrome-desktop-pc/

or may be, you can first record your screen and play it back later by using [adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/demo.mp4](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#screenrecord) and pull the file back using `adb pull /sdcard/demo.mp4`

Comment: I would avoid third-party solutions if your framework provides you with everything you need. Check this out https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#device-mirroring-giraffe